# Embedded AttributeOverride on update not working

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have entity with embedded two `ModelId` classes, where one is `EmbeddedId` and the other references another entity.

```
@Entity
public class Report implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private final ModelId id;

    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "scheme_id")
    @Embedded
    private ModelId schemeId;

    public void changeScheme(ModelId schemeId) {
        this.schemeId = schemeId;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class ModelId implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
}
```

I can **insert** and **select** `Report` but when I **update** the field `schemeId` I get:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [id] of class [mypackage.ModelId] is mapped
to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.
```

I use GlassFish 4.1 with EclipseLink 2.5.

Am I missing something or is it EclipseLink bug?

---

The problem is that only `id` makes primary key, `schemeId` is foreign key. When I change `schemeId` to **association** it **works fine**:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "scheme_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Scheme scheme;

public void changeScheme(Scheme scheme) {
    this.scheme = scheme;
}
```

I've been testing with many annotation combinations and also in GF4.0 and EclipseLink 2.6 with same result.

It seems like EclipseLink is ignoring `@AttributeOverride` during update and is mixing inner `schemeId.id` with `id.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same issue. It would appear that this defect is covered by an existing bug for eclipselink (against version 2.6.0, I still see this issue in 2.6.3):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=477638

It doesn't appear that there is any activity on this yet, so in the meantime I changed the `@EmbeddedId` to be just `@Embedded` and added a private primary key instead, like so:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int privateId;
```

I also added a composite unique constraint for the properties that were formerly part of the primary key. I had to change my `EntityManager.find(dataType, id)` calls as well to do a query instead. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception states you are modifying a primary key, Eclipselink does not permit this.
Two possible options are:
1) Delete old entity and create a new entity with new primary key.
2) Introduce a different attribute and define it as primary key, and provide unique constraint on these two fields.

Comment: Thanks for yout answer. May you look at my edit, please.