# embedded ids: primary key and foreign key

Tags: java, jpa

Given entity with embedded id and embedded foreign key:

```
@Entity
public class One {

  @EmbeddedId
  private ModelId id;

  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "two_id"))
  private ModelId twoId;
}

@Embeddable
public class ModelId {

  private Integer id;
}
```

when in JPQL:

```
SELECT o.id FROM One o WHERE o.twoId IN :twoId
```

then JPA generates SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM one WHERE id IN (?)
```

instead of:

```
SELECT id FROM one WHERE two_id IN (?)
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

put the keys inside `ModelID` entity and use a reference of it as PK inside entity `One`:

```
@Entity
public class One {

@EmbeddedId
protected ModelId modelPK;

//getter and setter

}

public class ModelId {

  @column(name="id")//give the real column name
  private int id;

  @column(name="towID")//give the real column name
  private int twoId;

 //getters and setters      
}
```

and then use below JPQL query:

```
SELECT o.modelPK.id FROM One o WHERE o.modelPK.twoId=:twoId
```

Comment: 1. I cannot change ModelId because I use it in all Entities.
2. This would set primary key on these two fields instead of only one - am I right?

Comment: If you can't change the `ModelId` so this answer is not the solution. and yes it sets a composite (on two fields) pk, anyway, I hope you'll fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I have so many troubles with this embedded class in JPA (there are always some defects that nobody can solve, like [this unanswered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940105/embedded-attributeoverride-on-update-not-working)) that I'll go in simple Integer.

Comment: You are welcome, but the problem is from base and when we say that, you say "I can't change it", anyway good luck and hope you'll solve them all.